# How to factorize the expression $4(ab+cd)^2-\left(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2\right)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, prime-factorization

> Factorise$$4(ab+cd)^2-\left(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2\right)^2$$

I can't solve this math assignment from my text book. No one knows how to solve it, so I would be so thankful to you if you presented your step-by-step solution. Thank you very much and I know this is probably an easy question for you, but I don't know the answer to it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Have a look at [ask], and please use the body of the Question to give Readers a full statement of the problem you want help with (not limiting its expression to your title as done here).  Include context, such as what you've already understood or attempted to solve the problem, so Readers can write a response appropriate to what you are finding difficult and not belabor definitions, etc. already covered to your satisfaction.  This [introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) will get you started with using mathematical expressions here.

Comment: I have reformatted the question - this makes it also easier to see what might be going on. Quite often with these types of question the key phrase is "difference of two squares" or the basic quadratic identities $(x\pm y)^2= x^2\pm 2xy+y^2$

Answer (score 3):

$$4(ab+cd)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2=$$
$$(2(ab+cd)-a^2-b^2+c^2+d^2)(2(ab+cd)+a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)=$$
$$=((c+d)^2-(a-b)^2)((a+b)^2-(c-d)^2)=$$
$$=(c+d-a+b)(c+d+a-b)(a+b-c+d)(a+b+c-d).$$

Comment: You know,these are the kinds of basic baby calculations you "forget" how to do after a few years proving theorems and it's really critical to retain the skills of. That's why refreshing yourself with these kinds of problems is always a good idea.